# How do I display text in the middle of a dialog as well as a new line?

Tags: applescript

I am currently making an AppleScript and would like to know how to do the following things.

- Display text in the center of a `display dialog`
- How to create a new line inside the dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a second line use `\n` or just hit enter when you want the new line:

```
display dialog "Test\nTest2"
```

or

```
display dialog "Test
Test2"
```

About the center alignment, I think that is not possible.

Comment: @user121028 just the same. `"Hello, \n" & currentuser & "!\n"...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use CocoaAppleScript to do this. Create one by going into Script Editor's "New from Template" menu in the File menu, and "Cocoa-AppleScript Applet.app". Modify html_data's HTML code to get it to be how you want it. Try it out!:

```
set alert to current application's NSAlert's new
set alert's messageText to ""
set text_field to current application's NSTextField's alloc's initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 88)
set text_field's drawsBackground to false
set text_field's editable to false
set text_field's bezeled to false
set html_data to (current application's NSString's stringWithString:("<center><font size=\"80\">Welcome!<br>Another welcome!</font></center>"))'s dataUsingEncoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)
set text_field's attributedStringValue to (current application's NSAttributedString's alloc's initWithHTML:html_data documentAttributes:(current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithObject:(current application's NSFont's fontWithName:"Palatino-Roman" |size|:12) forKey:(current application's NSFontAttributeName)))
set alert's accessoryView to text_field
alert's runModal
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it is for my purpose too long and too complex.